# Why Huawei Push Kit is not working after publishing app?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, huawei-push-notification

I build an app for Huawei devices in which Push Kit is implemented successfully. I published that app to App Gallery.
After downloading my app **from App Gallery**, **Push Notification** is **not working**.
But when I am running that app from **my own system** (directly from android studio), it is **working fine**.

Comment: Agree with @[mohax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3212712/mohax)'s answer, You are advised to check the fingerprints, and if that's all right, pls provide a detailed log for us to check.

Comment: I cross checked, SHA-256 key is correct, unable to find solution yet.
When I am generating release apk locally, it is working perfect but when I am downloading it from Huawei App Gallery, notifications are not working.

Comment: hi@Faizan Ahmad, Could you mind provide the APK downloaded from the AppGallery for us to check this issue? you could send it to hmscore@huawei.com, also, It would be nice if you could reproduce the problem and provide complete log.

Comment: Okay I will, But I tested a lot, facing same issue yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huawei is generating 2 SHA-256 keys, one locally. Second at App Signing module at developer account. After adding both SHA-256 keys, my issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

99% that you use different signing keys. I.e. you've enabled signing of app by app gallery. So you have to add SHA-256 mentioned in AGC to project settings, where you have debug SHA-256 from AndroidStudio.

Comment: I am already using SHA-256 key.